# Continue playing a sound when pressed down in android studio

Tags: android, piano

I have a sound with 4 duration. I want to play continuously this sound by pressing down without stopping it, like piano keys when you pressing down, it plays a sound without looping or stopping.

```js
c.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            switch (event.getAction()) {
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // Button Pressed
                          soundPool.stop(SID1_c);                                        
                         SID1_c = soundPool.play(sound_c, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
                                c.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.key4);
                                   return true;
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:// Button released

                                    handler =new Handler();
                                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            soundPool.stop(SID1_c);
                                        }
                                    },90);

                                    return false;

                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: can you atleast provide some kind of code that you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
  onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
     switch(getActionMasked()){
       case ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS:
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        soundPool.stop(SID1_c);                                        
        SID1_c = soundPool.play(sound_c, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
        c.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.key4);
        return true;

       case ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE:
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        soundPool.stop(SID1_c);
                                    }
                                },90);
       return false;
     }
     return false;
  }
});
```

your code problem:
if you tap button two times
when you start post delayed for stopping sound for first button up this stopping will hit second press not the first one which has been stopped before
to correct this you should exit handler when you play the sound
you can use `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` when a new press is done

Comment: when I pressing down, the sound plays very well and when pressing up stop it. but when I pressing rapidly and several times it doesn't play my sound very good. I want to create a piano app by this ability that you can press key and play sound till you release it.

Comment: your code problem: if you tap button two times when you start post delayed for stopping sound for first button up this stopping will hit second press not the first one which has been stopped before to correct this you should exit handler when you play the sound

Comment: I try it but don't work. I put this code after 90); don't work and also I put it like in your code and unfortunately crash... Thank you very much. yes, I'm Iranian.

Comment: you could add ( handler = new Handler() ) in beginning of onTouch event. what was exception message?

Comment: when I pressing rapidly and several times it doesn't play my sound very good. Don't work

Comment: when pressing button two times after releasing first press you start post delayed for stopping sound command for first release but this stopping command will hit second press not the first one to correct this you should stop handler when you play the sound